# How to align legends in pie charts dynamically pointing towards pie chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am new to Highcharts and having a couple of questions while dealing with Highcharts.

1. Legend in the data label of the pie chart should be exactly the center of the slice.
2. The percentage value should flow around the legend in Pie chart.

```
From the example:
1.Percentage value residing next to the triangle
2.Percentage value is below the square.
3.Percentage value is above the diamond.
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/chay2443/pen/rNLoXKo)

> Note: Please ignore shapes in the codepen.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Please feel free to answer any of the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this demo is a good start to implement those features. Please analyze it.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a23ckv8n/

```
events: {
  load() {
    let chart = this;

    chart.series[0].points.forEach(p => {
      const DL = p.dataLabel;

      if (p.half) {
        const x = DL.translateX + chart.plotLeft + DL.getBBox().width;
        const y = DL.translateY + chart.plotTop + DL.getBBox().height;

        chart.renderer.circle(x, y, 5).attr({
          fill: p.color,
        }).add();

      } else {
        const x = DL.translateX + chart.plotLeft;
        const y = DL.translateY + chart.plotTop;

        chart.renderer.circle(x, y, 5).attr({
          fill: p.color,
        }).add();
      }
    })
  }
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#circle